# Match a SpecFlow feature step with double quotes inside of a string

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a step

```
Then I must see the 3 text text text "Text" as one of the search results
```

And a step definition

```
[Then(@"I must see the (.*) as one of the search results")]
```

No matter which symbols I add to the regex `"`,`'` in the step definition I get

```
"3 text text text \"Text\""
```

In this case, I don't want to escape quotes, but to grab the exact match of predefined data in a step.

Comment: you see the escaped quotes when you print the result to the console or when you are in the debugger?

Comment: @Jawad I see the escaped quotes when I am in the debugger. My assert fails after this. Because I expected the exact match with predefined input.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code for the step definition as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, I don't want to escape quotes, but to grab the exact
> match of predefined data in a step.

I believe you are looking to grab exact match of quotes . In that case , one of the implementation could be using [doc string](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html)

Gherkin would be

```
Then I must see below text as one of the search results

  """
  3 text text text "Text" 
  """
```

and step definition would be

```
 [Then(@"I must see below text as one of the search results")]
    
            public void docStringOnlyTest(string docString)
            {
                
                log.Info(docString);
            }
```

This will log `3 text text text "Text"` on console

doc string is captured as last parameter in step definition and is defined by triple quotes `"""`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What if a step like I mentioned above is in the middle of a scenario? Is this approach still work?